# Does groupby in Python result in a column or dataframe?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

Lets say I have a dataframe as

```
age Late
1     1
2     5
3     48
4     46
5     6
```

...

I want to replace all values in `Late` that are 46 or 48 with the median of `Late`. I believe the command is

```
trainDF.groupby('Late').transform(getmedian)
```

however, is the result the whole dataframe `trainDF`? or is it just the `Late` column?

That is, does the below make sense?

```
trainDF=trainDF.groupby('Late').transform(getmedian)
```

Or does the below make sense?

```
newLate = trainDF.groupby('Late').transform(getmedian)
```

I tried

```
newLate = trainDF.groupby('Late').transform(getmedian)
newLate.max()
```

prints out `Unnamed: 0`

and `trainDF['newLate'].max()`

prints out `KeyError: 'newLate'`

If I try

```
trainDF=trainDF.groupby('Late').transform(getmedian)
```

and print out

```
trainDF['Late'].max()
```

it says `KeyError: 'Late'`

What am I supposed to do to store the new data frame that replaces the 46 and 48 values in `Late`? I ask because I eventually want to make sure this works by printing out the max value of the modified `Late` column, and make sure it shows 6 (or any number less than 46), not 48

Comment: Side note: it looks like you're mixing Python and R syntax with `<-`...

Answer (score 2):

You'e asking a lot of questions here, but I'll address what seems to be the main one:

> I want to replace all values in Late that are 46 or 48 with the median of Late.

You can do that this way:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'age': [1,2,3,4,5],
                       'Late': [1,5,48,46,6]})
>>> df.loc[df['Late'].isin([46, 48]), 'Late'] = df['Late'].median()
>>> df
   Late  age
0     1    1
1     5    2
2     6    3
3     6    4
4     6    5
```

Comment: I noticed that you changed your answer so your first version would issue a warning then?

Comment: I forgot to select the ``Late`` column so it was modifying the whole dataset. I did a quick fix to make it work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good one liner for you:

```
trainDF["Late"].loc[(trainDF["Late"] == 48) | (trainDF["Late"] == 46)] = trainDF["Late"].median()
```

Bear in mind that groupby didn't really apply in your case and that it returns a `DataFrame`-ish object

Comment: when I try this and then print out the max value of `df['Late']`, it gives me the correct value, not 48. However, when I try to display a histogram, it still looks like it did before, showing values for 46 and 48:     `hplot = trainDF['Late'].hist(bins=10);
fig = hplot.get_figure();
fig.savefig("hist", format='pdf')`

Comment: Have you substituted `df` with `trainDF` when you ran it? In my computer the histogram looks normal. I edited the post for you